# static block vs private static method for static member initialization

Tags: java, methods, static-methods

A static variables can be initialized with the private static methods or with a static block. Are there any subtle difference between the two? Are there any situation where I cannot use the static method for initializing static members? I found the later more readable.

Static Block initialization :

```
private static int NUM_ITER;
static {
    // Operations
    NUM_ITER = //val from above operations.
}
```

Private static method initialization:

```
private static int NUM_ITER = calculateNumIter();

// Some method comment on how we are calculating.
private static int calculateNumIter()
{
    // Operations.
    return //value_from_operations.
}
```

I prefer the second one since it is more readable. Are there any situation I have to use only first (static blocks) ?

What is the best coding convention/design for initializing static members(final as well as variable)? Even from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8189473/static-block-vs-static-method-initializing-static-fields) I learned private static methods have an advantage over the static blocks.

thanks,

Comment: I have forgotten the static a few times for the static block, ever since i use version 2 ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `static Initializer` block (Your 1 option) executes when the JVM loads the class, even **before** any `static` variable is initialized.
2. Its a good place to have all the static variables at once.
3. Your second option can be optionally used to initialize **multiple** `static` variables by passing multiple arguments to the parameter of the initializing method.

Comment: In my example, the calculateNumIter() will be called during the JVM initialization. Isn't it?

Answer (score 3):

The static block would be necessary (or at least useful) if two different variables are interdependant and can't be initialized independently.

Suppose you need to read two values from a file, for example. You could store both values in an additional object. But if you really want two constants, a static block is useful.

Comment: So, again the static method can replace static block here.

Comment: That works if the second is derived from the first. But if both are derived from a single value, it doesn't. Suppose you need to read two values from a file, for example.

Comment: Yes, but what if your first static method accepts your second static member as arg, too?

Comment: @LastStar007 Yes, in this case, it will induce a dependancy that the static members cannot be re-shuffled in the code. Also it place a dependancy in the static block that the block should be after declaration of the two members, but I agree the static block will be neater in this case rather two static methods.

Comment: I actually was replying to a different comment, which has since been revised or deleted or something.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to use whatever syntax keeps your code clean and readable:

- if the initialization amounts to one, max two, very simple lines of code, then go with the static block;
- if the initialisation is a complex operation, then a method with a good name will be best;
- in doubt, use the method syntax and use the method name to declare not only which variable, but also how you are initializing (i.e. initializeValueWithRandomNumber() );